# Android 2.1+ Pause for incoming/outgoing call, resume when done

Tags: android, phone-call, audio-player

Is there a reliable way in Android to detect the beginning and end of incoming and outgoing calls, in order to do things like pause and play audio.

I have done the following:

```
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            callEventListener = new PhoneStateListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                        //....
                    }
                    else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                        //....
                    }
                }
            };
telephonyManager.listen(callEventListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Which seems to work for incoming calls, but for outgoing calls I get the CALL_STATE_IDLE when the other person picks up...not when the phone call ends. I figure I must be doing something stupid, or missing something else that I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that you don't get any state updates when a out going call is started.

You need to hook into the intent broadcast [ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL).  Here is a [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) that may help understand the fact that it's a ordered broadcast.  And here is a [blog post](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1151) with a simple example of how to setup and use this broadcast.