# How to handle a call in android media player?

Tags: android, media-player, broadcastreceiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android 2.1+ Pause for incoming/outgoing call, resume when done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673368/android-2-1-pause-for-incoming-outgoing-call-resume-when-done)

I have created a mediaplayer in android and everything works fine except that the player keeps on playing when i receive a call. To **handle a call** i think we should use **broadcast receiver** and listen to **phone state**. But being a beginner i couldnt figure out **how to implement it?**.Please help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set up [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html), specifically paying attention to "onCallStateChanged method, and send commands to the media player as appropriate based on call state (pause when ringing, resume after hangup if so desired, etc).

Comment: can u please post the manifest file and PhoneStateListener code